# Prolog How can I sort a list like this

Tags: prolog

Hey guys I'm trying to sort a list that looks like this:

```
[peter-3, mark-2, sam-1]
```

to give:

```
[sam-1, mark-2, peter-3]
```

I tried editing the code for insertion sort, but it doesn't seem to work, it returns 'false'.

```
insert_sort(List,Sorted):-i_sort(List,[],Sorted).

i_sort([],Acc,Acc).
i_sort([H-N1|T],Acc,Sorted):- insert(H-N1,Acc,NAcc),
                          i_sort(T,NAcc,Sorted).

insert(X-N1,[Y-N2|T],[Y|NT]):- N1>N1,insert(X-N1,T,NT).
insert(X-N1,[Y-N2|T],[X-N1,Y-N2|T]):- N1=<N2.
insert(X-N1,[],[X-N1]).
```

Comment: No errors. It returns 'false'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplistic approach would be to map it to a list easily sorted with `msort/2`, then map it back to its original form:

```
num_name(Name-Num, Num-Name).
name_num(Num-Name, Name-Num).

sort_names_by_num(UnsortedNameNum, SortedNameNum) :-
    maplist(num_name, UnsortedNameNum, UnsortedNumName),
    msort(UnsortedNumName, SortedNumName),
    maplist(name_num, SortedNumName, SortedNameNum).
```

Regarding your attempt at modifying the insertion sort, you have a coule of typographical errors:

```
insert(X-N1,[Y-N2|T],[Y|NT]) :- ...
```

should be:

```
insert(X-N1,[Y-N2|T],[Y-N2|NT]) :- ...
```

And `N1 > N1` should be `N1 > N2`. Then your solution works!

```
insert_sort(List, Sorted) :- i_sort(List, [], Sorted).

i_sort([], Acc, Acc).
i_sort([H-N1|T],Acc, Sorted) :-
    insert(H-N1, Acc, NAcc),
    i_sort(T, NAcc, Sorted).

insert(X-N1, [Y-N2|T], [Y-N2|NT]) :-
    N1 > N2,
    insert(X-N1, T, NT).
insert(X-N1, [Y-N2|T], [X-N1,Y-N2|T]) :- N1 =< N2.
insert(X-N1, [], [X-N1]).
```

Comment: Thank you, it works well with mapping. I tired insertion sort after fixing that typo, but it still returns 'false' I don't really understand why.

Comment: @yasseen.hesham I'm sure if you comb through your solution and compare again carefully with the original insertion sort, you'll likely find it. It should be isomorphic to the original.

Comment: @yasseen.hesham  I noticed you also have `N1 > N1` in your code. Just make that `N1 > N2` and it works. :)